# How to execute multiple operations at once using sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I know about transactions, but the way it's handled in callbacks, makes it look like the DB is hit once. After that it is communicated back to the server, and as a result, the serves takes on the next operation and so on.

I want to make multiple unrelated operations at once, to be really efficient (not chaining)

Like:

`user.destroy();
post.create({...});
anotherPost.destroy();`

They are all independent and don't need to be chained. I just want to execute all those at once. How can I do that?

Comment: What you have tried? And what kind of errors did you get?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way here is to use Promise.props, like:

```
var promises = {
     userDestroy = user.destroy(),
     postCreate = post.create(),
     postDestroy = anotherPost.destroy()
};

sequelize.Promise.props(promises).then(function(results) {
  /// each promise is resolved here, results:
  results.userDestroy;
  results.postCreate;
  results.postDestroy;
});
```

Here's more info: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html Or you can use `.all` if you need an array of promises: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html